# replacing a placeholder in a html file with 1-n specific values defined in a config.json using shellscript

Tags: node.js, regex, bash, shell, perl

### The Problem:

I need to replace a placeholder (`__PLACEHOLDER__`) in a html file index.html with 1-n specific values defined in a config.json file.

### what I tried:

replacing the placeholder inside index.html with new content: 
`echo "${html//__PLACEHOLDER__/$replace}" > index.html`

getting the values from json (not working): 
`replace=$(sed 's/.*"host": "\(.*\)"/\1/g;d;t' config.json)`
this is not a good approach and currently does not return the desired values

So i know how to replace the value in the html file, but i dont know **how to get the values i need into a variable** before that. I already tried it with sed or perl, with sed however the issue is its not cross platform compatible which it need to be.

#### config.json:

```
{
    "xxxx": {
        "description": "xxxxx",
        "value": {
            "to": [
                "xxxxxx"
            ]
        }
    },
    "xxxx": {
        "description": "xxx",
        "value": "xxxxxx"
    },
    "API": {
        "description": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "value": {
            "default": {
                "host": "VALUE I WANT"
            },
            "auth": {
                "host": "VALUE I WANT"
            }
        }
    },
}
```

default and auth are only some possible values it could be 1-n hosts.

in the end i would like a variable with all the hosts as strings: host1 host2 host3

info: *we cannot use any 3rd party tools which are not usually present on systems & the index.html file is of no interest, we just replace the placeholder value.*

I appreciate your help

Comment: You say you _can't use 3rd party tools that are not usually present on system_, yet you now have tagged with _node.js_. You don't tell us what your usual systems look like, or what you deem 3rd party. In Perl, for example, this is easily doable with systems that bring Perl 5.14 out of the box, because it includes a JSON parser in core. Pretty much any Linux distribution that's been released in the last 10 years will have it. You'll have to write fewer than 10 lines of code. But you are not particularly clear about your requirements, so I am afraid I can't help you.

Comment: Can you give us a (small) sample input file along with the output that you would expect?

Answer (score 2):

> we cannot use any 3rd party tools which are not usually present on systems

Given that we don't know what "systems" you're using, this isn't a very useful restriction to tell us about.

Perl has several JSON parsers available and since Perl 5.14 (which was released in May 2011) one of them ([JSON::PP](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::PP)) has been part of the standard Perl distribution. So if you have a version of Perl that was released in the last nine years, then the task of reading the JSON file into a variable is trivial.

```
#!/user/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use JSON::PP;
use Data::Dumper;

open my $json_fh, '<', 'config.json' or die $!;

my $json = do { local $/; <$json_fh> };

my $config = JSON::PP->new->decode($json);

# Now you have your JSON in a Perl data structure
say Dumper $config;

# You can also access individual values
say $config->{xxxx}{description};
say $config->{API}{value}{default}{host};
```

Comment: Is it possible to submit `{API}{value}{default}{host}` as argument(s) to your script?

Comment: @Cyrus: Well, you can perpetuate all sorts of monstrosities using `eval` but I really wouldn't recommend it. Probably better to pass in a representation of the keys you need to use - perhaps "API:value:default:host" and then write code to parse that and use the information to look data up in the hash.