# find and extract substring from string

Tags: json, bash

This command

```
ubus -S call system board
```

gives me this output

```
{"kernel":"4.14.195","hostname":"OpenWrt","system":"ARMv7 Processor rev 1 (v7l)","model":"Linksys WRT32X","board_name":"linksys,venom","release":{"distribution":"OpenWrt","version":"19.07.4","revision":"r11208-ce6496d796","target":"mvebu/cortexa9","description":"OpenWrt 19.07.4 r11208-ce6496d796"}}
```

I want to just extract the model and, if there's a space, replace it with an underscore so I end up with

```
Linksys_WRT32X
```

Answer (score 2):

Your command output is json, you can extract the value of the "model" field in pure text and use `sed` to replace any spaces with underscore.

```
<command> | jq -r '.model' | sed 's/ /_/g'
```

or using one `jq` command to select and replace the text value (thanks @Cyrus)

```
<command> | jq -r '.model | sub(" "; "_")'
```

If you don't have `jq` here is an `awk` for this

```
awk -v RS=, -F: '$1 ~ /model/{gsub(/\"/,""); gsub(" ","_"); print $2}'
```

Have in mind, that one awk or sed for this specific output is fine, but if this was for any json, it could break, json is not text, it can be printed in various lines, it can have additional spaces in places etc.

Comment: Is it possible to do it if the command jq is not available?

Comment: @Fr3nZy: In this case I suggest to use `perl` and its JSON parser. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62344545/3776858

Comment: Looks like it only outputs in JSON format.  -S will keep it as a single line.

Comment: @Cyrus It's a limited function bash shell.  I only have access to sed awk and grep without having to install additional packages.

Comment: I got this.  It's very messy but gets it done ``ubus -S call system board | awk -F\",\" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' | grep 'model' | sed 's/^\(model":"\)*//' | sed 's/ /_/g'``.  Can it be condensed?

Comment: see also what to do after [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Here's another one:

```
ubus -S call system board | sed 's/.*"model":"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/' | tr ' ' _
```

Answer (score 0):

I would attempt to answer this using my own version. Since `GNU grep` has support for Perl regex, we can get the result using:

```sh
ubus -S call system board | grep -oP '"model":"\K[^"]+' | tr ' ' _
```

We attempt to take advantage of the pattern that the JSON key-value pair is of the form `"key-name":"<value>"` and try to capture the `<value>` part using `grep`.