# How to update the tag values(String and Integers) in JSON using shell script

Tags: json, bash, sed

I have one JSON file which contains three tags and I am trying to update the tag values using `sed` command.

`demo.json`

```
{
   "useCaseName" : "demo",
  "useCaseNumber" : 12,
   "Case" : 221
}
```

I am trying to invoke the below function and pass the tag and value as an argument to update the JSON file

```
change(){
    sed -i '/'${1}'/c\   \"'${1}'\" : "'${2}'",' demo.json
}
change "useCaseName" "hello"
change "useCaseNumber" 2
```

Now the problem is the above command is adding the double quotes to the `useCaseNumber` like below.

```
{
   "useCaseName" : "hello",
   "useCaseNumber" : "2",
   "Case" : 221
}
```

Is there any way to update both string value and Integer value using the above function?

Comment: That's how you do it: `jq '.useCaseName="foo" | .useCaseNumber="2"' demo.json`

Comment: unfortunately, I can't use `jq`.So I am trying with `sed`

Comment: In this case I suggest to use [Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62344545/3776858) with its JSON parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `sed` and `bash` if `jq` and `Perl` are not available:

```
change() { sed -Ei 's/(\"{0,1})'"$1"'(\"{0,1}) : (\"{0,1})[^,"]*(\"{0,1})/\1'"$1"'\2 : \3'"$2"'\4/' demo.json; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just check if the second variable is number or not using regex. If it is number, then don't add the quotes and vice versa for text. The modified script is

```
change(){
    re='^[0-9]+$'

    if ! [[ $2 =~ $re ]] ; then
        #if second argument is text
        sed -i '/'${1}'/c\   \"'${1}'\" : "'${2}'",' demo.json
    else
        #if second argument is number
        sed -i '/'${1}'/c\   \"'${1}'\" : '${2}',' demo.json
    fi
   
}
change "useCaseName" "hello"
change "useCaseNumber" 2
```